# powerpivot populate fact table from a CSV file

Tags: csv, powerpivot, dimension, datamodel, fact-table

I'm trying PowerPivot to analyze some amounts.

I have prepared my databus Matrix, created the data model, created and populated all the dimensions tables.

Now I know how my fact table is supposed to look like with all the foreign key of the my dimensions plus the amounts.

Aside from that I have as a source file a CSV file. Each columns of this csv file is related to a value (a row) inside of the dimensions, and the last 3 columns are the amounts that has the analytical value.

My issue here is that I don't know how, from this csv file, to populate my fact table with all the necessary FK + the amounts.

Comment: Typically that is done in ETL.  If your dimension has 1 row per source key (doesn't keep history like type 2 SCD) and also contains the source system IDs, you might be able to make your relationship on your source system ID rather than on surrogate keys.

Comment: You could also try to do this with Power Query

Comment: @mmarie any tips for ETL-related resources?

Comment: Try Power Query first, as it is part of Excel.  Otherwise, you will be building a whole data mart.